# pre verfying error while compiling J2me project

Tags: eclipse, java-me, jackson

I am using some jackson jar file for J2me project. this project regarding to parsing XML string using ObjectMapper class. 
 it s giving Preverfying error class When i am going to compile the application. 
could you please suggest how can we resolve that error??

Thaks 
Uday

Answer (score 0):

I do not think Jackson is not compatible with JavaME that is why it fails to preverify. Use something like json.me for parsing JSON.

If you are using XML I would recommend a pull parser and implement the parsing logic. [Here](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/XML_Parser_in_Java_ME) is a good example that shows how to do that

Comment: Okay, i ill. and one more query here, i have an String variable that contains XML tags, i wanted to convert that XML string to Object.  could u post some codes?

Comment: Updated with XML parser recommendation